# declaracion variable Dictionary swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

Tengo una funcion para obtener las coordenadas según dirección.

Tengo que declarar una variable como `dictionary` para transformar un resultado en json.

```
var error: NSError?

let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente

```
Extra argument 'error' in call
```

debo decir que me estoy guiando con la docu de google maps

por lo cual ese trozo de codigo lo obtuve de hay por lo que no se cual puede ser el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese método está `deprecated` y debes utilizar la nueva forma con `do catch` tal que así:

```
do {

    let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

} catch {

    print(error)

}
```

Si quisieras evitar el control de errores (no te lo recomiendo) puedes hacerlo así:

```
let dictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
```

Comment: gracias mhergon, funciono